# How to Make Page in UIWebView fit to the WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to display a page in `UIWebView` in iPad.

It is fitting to browser completely in any browsers but in `UIWebView` it is not fitting vertically.

Also it is displaying perfectly in `iPhone`.

Please help.

EDIT :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView {
    if (webView == myWebView) {
        [loadingView setHidden:YES];

        CGSize contentSize = myWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
        CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

        float scale = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;
        if (scale < 0.9) {
            NSLog(@"Zoom out fix for web view: %f", scale);

            webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale;
            webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale;
            webView.scrollView.zoomScale = scale;
        }
    }
}
```

Also have Tried all sorts of combinations in this.

```
myWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill | UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
myWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
myWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Comment: Have you set `webView.scalesPageToFit = true` ?

Comment: Already tried it but no luck

Comment: hello, give code that you have tried

Comment: if possible can you share URL or webpage source you are trying to load to try some tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how the webView.xib is loaded, here is an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eztcjwdf8lj4fms/WebViewTest.zip?dl=0) of loading a webView.xib and by setting its constraints: top space to super view, leading space to super view and center in superview, it works fine.

Comment: Agreed check this vid which shows how to preview phone and ipad simultaneously when you set the constraints. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk

Comment: Thank you @gabbler for your efforts and response. I tried loading my URL from your project and again the result is the same.

Comment: What the URL address? Can you share it?

Answer (score 2):

I found this, I'm not sure if you tried already but maybe is worth it to give it shot if you haven't found any solutions for this.

Do it in the `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` method [apple documentation here!](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad:)

Then, try using javascript for this.. (you can change the zooming value) btw, only positives values..

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

The only thing about this, is that it will happen after the page is loaded but, you can still only show the page after it loads..

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The statement will make your work done.

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

This should size the web page to fit the size of the UIWebView, and user then has the option to zoom in and out of the page.

Comment: @g4genuis where are you setting the scalesPageToFit to true ?

Comment: @sigkill Have tried putting it on `ViewDidLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` both

Comment: @g4genuis put it after you have initialized the webview but before webViewDidFinishLoad method.

Comment: @sigkill I think putting in `viewDidLoad` will serve the same purpose coz my `UIWebView` is in XIB. Thanks for suggestion but have tried that too.

Comment: @g4genuis try setting the scale pages to fit from the Attribute Inspector as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

**Note:** Website must be `responsive site` to fit in screen as like you expected.

- Add `UIWebViewDelegate` delegate to you **.h** file `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>`

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     //-- Create valid Url by replacing space into %20
     NSString *urlTextEscaped = [UrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlTextEscaped];
     NSLog(@"URL = %@",url);
     NSURLRequest *requestconn = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     webview.delegate = self;
     webview.scalesPageToFit =YES;

     //-- Load URL in WebView
     [webview loadRequest:requestconn];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SVMRAJESH for the response. This also I tried but don't know why not getting desired result. And the site is working on normal browsers as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In apple documentation it says [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scalesPageToFit).

You are probably doing something wrong...try comment all the unnecesary code beside setting the content inside webview to localize the problem.

Try make your webview a property, check delegates if they gets called, check if you're filling webview the right way...etc.

Try commenting this :

```
   CGSize contentSize = myWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    float scale = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;
    if (scale < 0.9) {
        NSLog(@"Zoom out fix for web view: %f", scale);

        webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale;
        webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale;
        webView.scrollView.zoomScale = scale;
    }
```

and any other stuff to find where your problem is. This is how you should resolve a problem.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thank you @Silviu St for your input. Tried this before hand. I was loading the content without any settings. But now for this URL only it is giving this kind of issue. Don't know what to do.

Comment: i can't tell you why.. don't know what the problem is...you should check  compile for ios 7 and for ios 8... and on a real device..not simulator..

Comment: I am running this on my iPad only. Will check in IOS 7 device.